# android:layout_below keep overlapping views

Tags: android, android-layout

I've just a little problem with my layout. Here it is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Beige"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/strip_popular"
    style="@style/StripsHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/home_popular" >
</TextView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_popular"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/strip_popular" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/popular_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/strip_latestreviews"
    style="@style/StripsHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/strip_popular"
    android:text="@string/home_latestreviews">
</TextView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_latestreviews"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/strip_latestreviews" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/latestreviews_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The problem I have is that the second textview completely overlaps the first one, instead of appearing below the horizontal scrollview.

In my code I insert images in this way:

```
LinearLayout popular = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popular_layout);

Integer[] mThumbIds = { 
            R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second,    
            R.drawable.third, R.drawable.fourth};


    for(Integer i : mThumbIds){

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(i);

        popular.addView(imageView);


    }
```

any advice?

Comment: You have android:layout_below="@id/strip_popular" at the scrollview and textview.

Answer (score 0):

In second TextView just replace

```
android:layout_below="@id/strip_popular"
```

with

```
android:layout_below="@id/scroll_popular"
```

Comment: @Tunarock Actually u want second TextView appears below the scrollview right. Scrollview id is "scroll_popular". So, u have to put layout_below of scroll_popular for that second TextView.

Comment: I've done that, but the result is the same, and also setting the height of the horizonal scroll doesn't change anything. I can't understand what view or what attribute does this thing happen.

Comment: what StripsHome style contains?

Comment: such an idiot I am. **Thank you!** The problem was exactly there, I setted android:layout_alignParentTop to true :S